# Dynamic iframe content with $_POST

Tags: php, html, post, iframe

PHP has always been kind of a problem for me. Normally I find my way with searching and trial and error, but this time I can't figure it out.

I'm currently working on a project where people can order services online. The ordering module is on a different domain which we frame using iframe. All the rest of the content is hosted on or own domain. When people browse through our services they can click a link where they order said service online. They are being lead to a page with a dynamic iFrame. The iFrame looks like this:

```html
<div id="outerFrame">
   <iframe id="innerframe" src="<?php echo $_POST['res']; ?>"   
            name="reserveer" frameborder="0"></iframe>    
</div>
```

The button that leads them there looks like this:

```html
<form method="post" action="iframepage.php">
<input type="hidden" name="res" value="http://requestedservice.com" />
<input type="submit" value="Order now"/>
</form>
```

And this works pretty great! The only problem is when people go to the iframe page, the page (or frame) is empty. I would like for the users to see a standard iframe src if they didn't go to the page with a "Order now" button. So I was trying to get something like this (and tried a lot of different approaches in the meantime):

```html
<?php
if ($_POST) {
 $resUrl =  "echo $_POST['res']"; 
} else {
 $resUrl = "http://standardframecontent.com";
}
?>
```

Where the frame now echos $resUrl.

Like I said, I tried a lot of different approaches. This is the first time I asked help online myself which means I'm pretty desperate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<iframe id="innerframe" src="<?= (isset($_POST['res']) ? $_POST['res'] : 'http://standardframecontent.com'); ?>" name="reserveer" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this seemed to do the trick and everything inside the iframe src! I just don't really get how you do the if/else (= / ? / :) statements like that. Then again, I'm pretty much a php noob.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried testing the post value like this?

```
if (isset($_POST['res'])) {
    $resUrl =  $_POST['res'];   
} else {
    $resUrl = "http://standardframecontent.com";
}


<div id="outerFrame">
    <iframe id="innerframe" src="<?php echo $resUrl; ?>"   name="reserveer" frameborder="0"></iframe>    
</div>
```

I test the var and then put it into a var. 
I print that var now, both case =)

Comment: Thank you, this also seemed to do the trick. I already tried isset before. I think I went wrong with trying to echo $_POST inside the $resUrl. I'm sorry, I can't upvote your solution due to the face I don't have enough rep :(.

Comment: Do not worry about upvote. Isset it needs to be used to variables or arrays but $_POST as a superglobal may have some different behavior. I find better programming solution with testing the single var or counting an array =)